# Is there a function in MYSQL like JSON_ARRAY_APPEND but for multiple vaues to be appended?

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to add multiple values in JSON_ARRAY_APPEND.

For example in the following query:

```
SET @data = '{  
    "Person": {    
       "Name": "Homer", 
       "Hobbies": ["Eating", "Sleeping"]  
    }
 }';
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@data, '$.Person.Hobbies', "Base Jumping") AS 'Result';
```

Our result would be:

> {"Person": {"Name": "Homer", "Hobbies": ["Eating", "Sleeping", "Base Jumping"]}}

I'd like to be able to add multiple hobbies in one line rather than a dozen, using something like

```
SET @data = '{  
    "Person": {    
       "Name": "Homer", 
       "Hobbies": ["Eating", "Sleeping"]  
    }
 }';
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@data, '$.Person.Hobbies', '"Base Jumping","Skiing"') AS 'Result';
```

Which results in

> {"Person": {"Name": "Homer", "Hobbies": ["Eating", "Sleeping", "\"Base Jumping\",\"Skiing\""]}}

That's almost what I want but has extra characters that aren't wanted. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()` allows you to specify multiple path and value arguments. You can repeat the same path, and it will append to the result of the preceding append.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@data, 
        '$.Person.Hobbies', "Base Jumping", 
        '$.Person.Hobbies', "Skiing") AS Result;
```

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append):

> The path-value pairs are evaluated left to right. The document produced by evaluating one pair becomes the new value against which the next pair is evaluated.

You can also use [`JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve) to concatenate arrays:

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(@data, '$.Person.Hobbies', '["Base Jumping", "Skiing"]') AS Result;
```

Comment: Great, I think that's what I was looking for. I tried finding documentation but could only find blogs that didn't explain this. Thanks a lot.